# Adding table names in oracle database to combo box in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I have tried to display the names of table in oracle database in visual studio 2012 in combo box but i am not sure why it is not displaying

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

               try
               {
                   con.Open();
                   OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT table_name FROM tabs where table_name Like 'ST%'", con);
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   oda.Fill(dt);
                   comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
                    con.Close();
               }

               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
               }

    }
```

Comment: You are applying a condition `Like 'ST%'`. Are you sure there are tables starting with `ST` ?

Comment: yup i test it in sql it works then i apply it in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. Instead double clicking on the combo box, i place the code at the contructor of the form, therefore everytime it loads, it automatically send the value to combo box